# Apply the siblings selector when the second operand has "hidden" attribute

Tags: html, css

### Intro

The [vue-slide-up-down](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-slide-up-down) plugin appends the attribute `hidden` to target element to hide it. According documentation, this method is preferred:

> #### "use-hidden" property
>
> Whether to apply the "hidden" attribute to the element when closed.
> Defaults to true. This hides the component from the screen and from
> assistive devices. The internal elements of the component are
> completely invisible, and cannot be focused on (by a keyboard or
> assistive device). (This is probably what you want!) If you need, set
> this property to false to not use the hidden attribute. This could be
> used if you wanted to have a min-height requirement on your component.
> **Note that this can create accessibility issues**, specifically for users with a keyboard or screen reader.
>
> [Source](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-slide-up-down#usage)

The problem is the element with `hidden` attribute obeys to Schrödinger paradox: "this elements is existing, but in the same time not existing". Below example shows what it means.

### Target

1. When the ".ControlsGroup" (designated by blue) is **visibly** last, it must provide the vertical space `l1` below self inside ".Container" (designated by light yellow):

[image]

2. When the ".ErrorsContainer" (designated by orange) is visible, it must retire `l2` px from ".ControlsGroup" and provide vertical space `l3` below self:

[image]

The **usage of padding-bottom of container is not allowed** because basically we don't know at advance what will be placed inside ".ControlsGroup", so each element MUST know:

1. How much to retire from specific previous element
2. How much of vertical space it needs to provide below self when going last.

```html
<div class="Container">
  <div class="ControlsGroup"></div>
   <div class="ErrorsContainer"></div>
</div>
```

### Problem

When `ErrorsContainer` is visible, everything is all right: in below example, `l2` is `24px` and `l3` is `36px`:

```css
.Container {
  background: #FFECB3;
  overflow: auto;
}

.ControlsGroup {
  height: 300px;
  background: #03A9F4;
}

.ErrorsContainer {
  height: 40px;
  background: #FF9800;
  margin-bottom: 36px;
}

.ControlsGroup + .ErrorsContainer {
  margin-top: 24px;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w7mzL5tv/)

Now, if to add `hidden` attribute to `.ErrorsContainer`, no `l1` space (between bottom of `.ControlsGroup` and bottom of `.Container`) will be:

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j5omg6wn/)

Let's try to add below CSS rule that means "when `.ErrorsContiner` with attribute `hidden` going after `.ControlsGroup`, push it to 12px (`l3`)":

```css
.ControlsGroup + .ErrorsContainer[hidden="hidden"] {
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}
```

Nothing will change. The effect like `.ErrorsContainer` does not exist.

Next, lets try to add below rule that means "When `ControlsGroup` going last, make 12px of extra space inside the parent":

```css
.ControlsGroup:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}
```

Nothing will change because `.ErrorContainer` actually exists and it's the last child.

Now how to define the `l3` when `.ErrorsContainer` is hidden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do some math here and consider `x` where `l1 + x = l2`. The idea is to always have the `l1` and when the `ErrorsContainer` is visible we add to it a margin-top equal to `x` to get `l2` instead of `l1`. I will also use flexbox to avoid margin collapsing and make sure the margin add and not collapse.

I am using CSS variables to illustrate but it's not mandatory:

```css
.Container {
  --l1:30px;
  --x:-15px; /* so l2 = 15px */
  --l3:10px;

  background: #FFECB3;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  overflow: auto;
  border:2px solid;
  margin:5px;
}

.ControlsGroup {
  height: 100px;
  background: #03A9F4;
}

.ErrorsContainer {
  height: 40px;
  background: #FF9800;
  margin:var(--x) 0 var(--l3);
}

.ControlsGroup {
  margin-bottom:var(--l1);
}
```

```html
<div class="Container">
  <div class="ControlsGroup"></div>
   <div class="ErrorsContainer" hidden></div>
</div>

<div class="Container">
  <div class="ControlsGroup"></div>
   <div class="ErrorsContainer"></div>
</div>
```